# Immediate, unwanted wakeup from sleep in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sleep, wake-up

I'm asking for a friend ;-). His computer (Windows 10) keeps waking up when he puts it into sleep mode. Prior to asking here I searched online a lot to solve the problem, but without success.

After such a random wakeup when you call `powercfg -lastwake` you get

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
 Wake Source Count - 1
 Wake Source [0]
  Type: Fixed Feature
  Power Button
```

When you call `powercfg -waketimers` you only get the standard

```
Timer set by [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe expires at 00:00:00 on 퀀凮♥.
```

I guess that this is standard since my computer has that as well and has no issues.

What can I check next?

Comment: Might have something to do with the mouse.

Comment: @TomYan No, we just tested it. We disconnected the mouse (by unplugging the USB cable) and put the computer into sleep mode using Windows short cuts (Win+X ...). After being for maybe 15 seconds in sleep mode it woke up again.

Comment: Wake on LAN maybe?

Comment: @TomYan We disconnected the LAN cable to make sure that it is not wake on LAN. It still woke up immediately after sleep.

Comment: 1. To see what *can* wake the PC, in CMD as Admin enter `powercfg.exe -devicequery wake_armed` 2. Check the Windows *Event Logs* for more information: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/179257-wake-source-read-event-viewer-log.html You might also try Nirsoft's *Full Event Log Viewer*, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html, to search for a specific string, e.g., "wake".

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I did check the windows event logs to confirm that the wake source is the power button. But most times the system wakes up without the power button pressed even though it says in the log that the reason is that button. Does my friend have a virus?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain, Might be a virus, but could also be a bad power switch button or pinched wires to it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik What would you suggest to do next? If it is no virus, you are sure now, that it is a hardware problem with the power button?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik By the way: It never occurs that the computer turns on if it is switched off. To turn it on you have to press the power button. If there was a problem with that power button, wouldn't that imply that the computer should have random turn ons if it is switched off as well?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain, those were some possibilities, but since you say the power switch never malfunctions when off, it is likely not the problem.  Check the BIOS settings, e.g., https://winaero.com/enable-or-disable-wake-on-lan-in-windows-10-wol/ and other wake settings. Or use Hibernate, which uses *no* power, as opposed to sleep, a constant drain.